# Using language in sql to pull everything where two criteria are not met

Tags: sql, oracle

If I wanted to pull data from a table call it sales where criteria is not met without doing a subselect what is the best way to do that.

I have been trying to pull all the data from the table where two criteria are not met

I am essentially trying to do

```
select * 
from  sales
where sales_id not in (select sales_id 
                       from  sales 
                       where sales_percentage<.02 
                         and sales_region in ('SW','SE'))
```

I tried the below but it isn't working as expected am I thinking about this incorrectly?

```
Select * 
from sales
where not(sales_percentage<.02 and sales_region in ('SW','SE'))
```

Comment: The sales ID is a primary key and is not repeated

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: `CREATE TABLE` statement and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; an explanation of what "but isn't working as expected" means; your expected output for the sample data.

Comment: Can `sales_percentage` or `sales_region` be `null`? If they can't be `null` then the queries should be equivalent. If they can be `null`, in general they won't be equivalent, but you will need to explain what the desired result is in such cases (before we can help you with your question); either the existing query or the new one - or both - will produce the *wrong* result.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it using analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT s.*,
         MIN(CASE WHEN sales_region IN ('SW', 'SE') THEN sales_percentage END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY sales_id)
           AS min_sales_percentage
  FROM   sales
)
WHERE  min_sales_percentage IS NULL
OR     min_sales_percentage >= 0.02
```

*Note: The above is untested as you have not provided any DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statement for your table structure or DML (`INSERT`) statements for your sample data to test it against.*

> I tried the below but it isn't working as expected am I thinking about this incorrectly?
>
> ```sql
> Select * 
> from sales
> where not(sales_percentage<.02 and sales_region in ('SW','SE'))
> ```

This will give different results to your original query when there are multiple rows with the same `sales_id` and some of those rows match your exclusion criteria and others do not; in this case your original query would exclude all the rows for that `sales_id` and this second query would only exclude rows a subset of the rows.

Comment: The sales id is a primary key and should not be repeated

Comment: What does this have to do with the OP's question? He is not looking for min sales percentage. I didn't check your solution closely, to see if it is equivalent to the OP's original query; but even if it is, why use analytic functions where they aren't needed? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @mathguy THe OP had not stated that `sales_id` was a primary key at the time this was written so there could have been multiple `sales_id` with different percentages; the OP wanted to exclude all common `sales_id` rows where there was any percentage less than 0.2 and finding the minimum percentage would tell you if that `sales_id` would be excluded. So, yes, in that case (when the OP doesn't give the information that `sales_id` is unique) it can be solved using the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of the first query, including `NULL` values for the comparands, would be:

```
select s.* 
from  sales s
where (sales_percentage >= 0.02 or sales_percentage is null) or
      (sales_region not in ('SW', 'SE') or sales_region is null);
```

You have specified that `sales_id` is the primary key, so it cannot have a `NULL` value (if it did, the original query might return no rows at all).